# Clearing cache using urllib library in python

Tags: python-2.7, urllib, clear-cache

I am downloading an image from a given url via urllib by using the

```
urllib.urlretrieve(ImageUrl,ImageName)
```

My question is: is it possible to clear cache using urllib before downloading the image or do I have to first browse to image url,clear cache, then download the image via urllib.urlretrieve?
I am using Python 2.7 ; browser: Chrome

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
urllib.urlcleanup()
```

It clears the cache that may have been built up by previous calls to urlretrieve().

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html